# What's the accepted way to handle values that can be different data types in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm basically reading a config file

`[Section]
Key=value`

Where the `value` can be either a string, an integer, a double, or a boolean value.

While working in this context, I have a class that looks like this...

```
public class Setting
{
    public string Section {get; set;}
    public string Key {get; set;}
    public <string, int, double, or bool> Value {get; set;}

    public Setting(string section, string key, <string, int, double, or bool> value)
    {
        Section = section;
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        //if Value is an int, call third-party code to write an integer to the config file.
        //if Value is a string, call third-party code to write a string to the config file.
        //...
    }
}
```

In this situation, what is the accepted way to handle the `Value` property of this class?

In addition, I'd like to be able to store a bunch of these objects in an Array, List, or other types of collections.

---

UPDATE:
I'm not reading/writing to the configuration file directly, that part of the code is not controlled by me.  Basically, I need to call different functions in the third-party code, based on the type of `Value`

---

UPDATE:
One thought was to use generics, and have a class like this...

```
public class Setting<T>
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public Setting(string section, string key, T value)
    {
        Section = section;
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
        {
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                //Call third-party code to write an integer
                break;
            case TypeCode.String:
                //Call third-party code to write a string
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But then I'd only be able to store a single type of setting in a List.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<Setting<string>> settings = new List<Setting<string>>();
```

So I'd have to have a list for each type of setting.

---

UPDATE:
Another option might be to use and interface, and classes for each type of setting that implement the interface...

```
interface ISetting
{
    string Section { get; set; }
    string Key { get; set; }

    void Write();
}

public class StringSetting : ISetting
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public StringSetting(string section, string key, string value)
    {
        Section = section;
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        //Call third-party code to write the setting.
    }
}
```

But that seems like a lot of duplicate code, so making changes in the future might be error prone.

---

UPDATE:
Another option, is to make `Value` a dynamic type.

```
public class DynamicSetting
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }

    public DynamicSetting(string section, string key, dynamic value)
    {
        Section = section;
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(Value.GetType()))
        {
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                //Call third-party code to write an integer
                break;
            case TypeCode.String:
                //Call third-party code to write a string
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can create a bunch of DynamicSetting objects, and store them in a collection like I want.

```
DynamicSetting IntSetting = new DynamicSetting("Section", "Key", 1);
DynamicSetting StringSetting = new DynamicSetting("Section", "Key", "1");
DynamicSetting DoubleSetting = new DynamicSetting("Section", "Key", 1.0);

System.Collections.Generic.List<DynamicSetting> settings = new List<DynamicSetting>();

settings.Add(IntSetting);
settings.Add(StringSetting);
settings.Add(DoubleSetting);

foreach(DynamicSetting setting in settings)
{
    setting.Write();
}
```

---

UPDATE:
I could also make `Value` an object

```
public class ObjectSetting
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public ObjectSetting(string section, string key, object value)
    {
        Section = section;
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(Value.GetType()))
        {
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                //Call third-party code to write an integer
                break;
            case TypeCode.String:
                //Call third-party code to write a string
                break;
            case TypeCode.Double:
                //Call third-party code to write a string
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And it would work just like dynamic

```
ObjectSetting IntSetting = new ObjectSetting("Section", "Key", 1);
ObjectSetting StringSetting = new ObjectSetting("Section", "Key", "1");
ObjectSetting DoubleSetting = new ObjectSetting("Section", "Key", 1.0);

System.Collections.Generic.List<ObjectSetting> settings = new List<ObjectSetting>();

settings.Add(IntSetting);
settings.Add(StringSetting);
settings.Add(DoubleSetting);

foreach(ObjectSetting setting in settings)
{
    setting.Write();
}
```

Comment: Well it depends. Sometimes I use `object` type... Sometimes generic `T` type.

Comment: It is a string.  Whether it can be converted depends, consider adding an enum type.  Don't use INI files.

Comment: Seems like your after a generic but as already stated it depends

Comment: The file contains a string. How you treat that string depends on *your* code. If you already know what each section contains you could create different classes per section, with specific typed properties for each settings. If you *don't* know what it contains, string is the only option

Comment: Maybe using generics will be relevant: 
public class Setting<T> and then property public T Value {get; set;} and constructor public Setting(T value) { Value = value;}

Comment: It all depends what "int stuff" and "string stuff" is. Can it be done as `object` or as a generic type? If not, inheritance is an option.

Comment: You can also .NET Core's configuration middleware in both .NET Core and Full Framework projects. The Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration package is a .NET Standard library that can be used by any runtime. You can use providers that read from INI, YAML, Json, XML files.

Comment: In the end though, you have to write the code that **parses** the string values into specific types. In the end, only you know if `Label=2018112` represents an integer, string or date.

Comment: I've updated the question to (hopefully) explain better what I'm trying to do

Comment: I tend to store them as "object" and then attempt to cast them to T.  I'd create converters for each type you could pass in, like "if T is int, return value casted to int".  I'd have a usage similar to `Config.Get<int>("myIntKey")`.  If you wanted to know the type BEFORE accessing them, you'd have to cast them before, perhaps in an initialisation routine somewhere, but then your config "get" return type would have to be Object...

Comment: _I need to call different functions in the third-party code, based on the type of Value_ and where do you get that type from?

Comment: @MattBurland (S)He'd have to parse it and "guess", I think.  An option would be to include the "type" in the config file maybe?

Comment: @MattBurland I know what type the value will be before I try to read it, but I want to be able to store all the settings in a single collection. I was also trying to avoid creating a class for each type of value, and making them derive from the same base class.

Comment: @Tester101: Since that is the correct solution, it is unclear to me why you are trying to avoid it. **Why are you trying to avoid the correct solution**?

Comment: Does the Value have to be exposed as a property?

Comment: Generics seem to be the cleanest solution as other users stated. But from what you commented maybe you should just set Value to dynamic and write some type checking code in  the Setting's Write() method. Dynamics are pure objects at run time but you can get rid of most type castings by using them.

Comment: Concerning your update with ISettings: You could avoid a lot of code if you just define an interface for the Value like ISettingsValue with a method Write() defined in it. No need to duplicate the other parts.

Comment: @Grimm Could you provide an example, I'm not sure what that would look like?

Comment: @Tester101 I gave an example below since it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to accept Value as an object in the constructor and the setter, both of which would validate the Type against your list of valid types.  Use a Switch in your Write method to determine which third-party code to call.  You can store all your Settings in a single collection.  Alternatively, you could write overloads for the constructor and a SetValue method.  That's a little more code, but would provide design time type-checking.

Answer (score 1):

Example for ISettingValue:

```
public interface ISettingValue
{
    void Write();
}

public class StringSetting : ISettingValue
{
    readonly string _data;
    public StringSetting(string data) => _data = data;
    public void Write() 
    {
        //Call third-party code to write the string (value of _data).
    }
}
public class IntSetting : ISettingValue
{
    readonly int _data;
    public IntSetting(int data) => _data = data;
    public void Write() 
    {
        //Call third-party code to write the integer (value of _data).
    }
}

public class Setting
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public ISettingValue Value { get; set; }

    public Setting(string section, string key, ISettingValue value)
    {
        Section = section;
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        Value.Write();
    }
}
```

Comment: So to create a Setting object, I'd have to do like this?... Setting setting = new Setting("Section", "key", new IntSetting(1));

Comment: Yes, exactly. You might use a factory pattern for object (Setting) creation, so that you call a single method with parameters Section, Key and dynamic/object Value. The factory method checks the type of value and returns Setting objects (with Value set to suitable objects implementing ISettingValue). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#

Comment: The Section and Key properties are readily available, but type for the Value property of the Setting class is an object that implements ISettingValue. That interface only exposes the Write() method.  How would you access the data of the underlying StringSetting or IntSetting object?  Even those do not expose the data publicly. Not criticizing, just wondering if I've missed something.

Comment: You're right, at the moment you can't access it from outside. If you need to access it you would need to add some code for that, e.g. turn _data into a property with a public getter or write a method like GetValue().

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that?

```
    public abstract class Setting {
    public abstract Type keyType { get; }
    public string Key { get; protected set; }
    public object value { get; protected set; }

    protected abstract Action writer { get; }

    public void Write() => writer();

}
public class Setting<T> : Setting {
    public override Type keyType => typeof(T);
    protected override Action writer => () => typeWriter(Value);

    public string Section { get; set; }
    public T Value {get; set;}

    private Action<T> typeWriter { get; }


    public Setting(string section, string key, T value, Action<T> writer) {
        Section = section;
        Key = key;
        this.value = Value = value;
        typeWriter = writer;
    }
}

public class Usage {
    private List<Setting> settings = new List<Setting>() {
        new Setting<double>("", "x", 10, n => Debug.WriteLine(n % 4)),
        new Setting<string>("", "y", "abc", s => Debug.WriteLine(s.ToUpper())),
        new Setting<bool>("", "z", true, b => Debug.Write(!b)),
    };

    public Usage() {
        foreach (var s in settings) {
            Debug.Write($"{s.keyType.Name} {s.Key} =");
            s.Write();
        }

    }
}
```